# PHP How to find all prices starting with $ or £ symbol within a string and replace them with bootstrap labels

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I have the following text:

> You can purchase the red umbrella for just $14.99 and the blue one for
>   £12.49. Limited time only

I want to find the **$14.99** price in the string and wrap the price within a bootstrap label tag and the same for **£12.49**.

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are looking for a regex solution, you can probably play around with it here and figure it out... http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: `preg_match_all("/[\$|£]\d+.\d+/", $text, $matches);` - you do the rest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make this work, but I have to do it for each currency. I only have 2 currencies so I'm fine with that.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<?php
$string = 'You can purchase the red umbrella for just $1455.99 and the blue one for $12.49. Limited time only.';
$pattern = '#\$(\d*)\.(\d*)#';
$replacement = '<span class="label label-success">$0</span>';
$string_with_price_replaced = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

echo $string_with_price_replaced;
?>
```

Thanks **Notorious Pet0** for [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com) website. Really useful.

Comment: You can always make an array of symbols $sym = ['$', '%', '#', '*', '@']; ... then foreach($sym as $v) { $pattern = '#\'.$v.'(\d*)\..(\d*)#';

Comment: you should mark your own answer correct and shoot me an upvote on mine.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP you can use [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) to get the position of every $ (and other symbol not on my keyboard)...

Then once you have the position, just make sure you are looking at a dollar amount by doing strpos again on the substring to find the nearest .(dot) after the $ etc...

```
<?php
$string = 'some stuff $14.99';
$pos = strpos($string, '$');
//pos = 11
$newstring = substr($string, $pos);
$dotpos = strpos($string, '.');
$yourfinalstring = substr($string, $pos, $dotpos + 2);
//your final string = $14.99
?>
```

In javascript just use [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

```
var string = 'some stuff $14.99';
var pos = string.indexOf('$');
// pos = 11
```

Comment: $yourfinalstring = substr($string, $pos, $dotpos + 2);  How do I know that there are only 2 digits after the .(dot)? It could be one or four maybe. And if you have only $14 the result will be $1 instead of $14

Comment: for a price?   really?  i thought you were dealing in dollars and L thingys

Comment: I have a hudge database and need to do this on 40k+ records. In these records could be a price that is $14.9999

Comment: Well in that case you would probably want to qualify every character after the . to see if its a number or not.

Comment: I am not saying is not good, but I want to find an easier solution. Maybe something with preg_match can be easier. I don't know that is why I asked.

Comment: You should put in your question your looking for a regex solution then.

Comment: There is reference and community and you can test regex here like on fiddle http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Im trying to figure it out too.  Making some progress.    I'm thinking preg_replace or preg_split, or maybe both.